# Limit through a figure

Tags: geometry, limits, functions

If a circular arc of radius $1$  subtends an angle of $x$ radians . The centre of the circle is $o$ and the point $c$ is the intersection of two tangents lines at $a$ and $b$ .

Now let $T(x)$ be the area of the triangle $abc$ .

Then we have to find $\lim_{x \to 0} T(x)/x^3$ .

I tried it , but don't get any start .

The figure is on :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\angle OAC = \angle OBC = \frac\pi2$, so $\angle ACB = \pi - x$. We also have $|AC| = |BC| = \tan(x/2)$. Now we may use the sine formula for the area:
$$
T(x) = \frac{|AC|\cdot |BC| \cdot \sin(\angle ACB)}{2} = \frac{\tan^2(x/2)\sin( x)}{2} 
$$
where I've used that $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin(x)$. To calculate $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{T(x)}{x^3}$, I would suggest using L'Hôpital's rule, or equivalently, power series. If neither of those are something you've heard about, then I probably need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the sector is $\frac x2$ and that of the triangle $2\cos\frac x2\sin\frac x2=\frac12\sin x$.

Then by Taylor

$$\frac12\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\left(x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o(x^3)\right)}{x^3}=\frac1{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image I have provided, I have marked the angles. In $\Delta$ OAB, $\sin{\frac{x}{2}}$ = $\frac{b}{1} $ and $\cos{\frac{x}{2}}$ = $\frac{c}{1}$ and from $\Delta$ ABC we get $\tan{\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{c}{b}$.
Now T(x) = $\frac{(2b)(c)}{2} = \sin^2{\frac{x}{2}} \tan{\frac{x}{2}} $. 
So $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{T(x)}{x} = \frac {(\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}} \tan{\frac{x}{2}})}{x^3} $.
Which gives us the answer $\frac{1}{8}$.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3uhV.jpg)